# How to texture map to a rotated surface in matlab?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, texture-mapping

I would like to texture map a 2D image to a 3D surface. I would like to do it in GUI so the user can rotate/shift/zoom the surface with the camera toolbar and then the image will be mapped to the visible portion of the surface.

I know I can get the camera position with `campos` command, but how do I get the camera orientation?

Any idea? Or maybe you can suggest a better approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To answer the question from your title (from what I understand), you can assign a texture map to 3D data using the accurately named `texturemap` value of the `FaceColor` property (original right?) as well as the appropriate `CData` (here a 2D image).

Simple example:

```
clear
clc

A = imread('peppers.png');

%// Generate dummy surface plot
[X,Y] = meshgrid([-2:.25:2]);
Z = X.*exp(-X.^2 -Y.^2);

surf(X,Y,Z,'CData',A,'FaceColor','texturemap')
```

It looks like this:

[image]

By default in a figure window you can zoom/move around as you want. For the 2nd part of your question, I think you should carefully read the docs for `campos` and related functions to get/set the camera position. Since building a GUI to perform that task requires much effort I think your best bet would be to try something on your own and ask questions about it here if you are stuck somewhere.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Nice example, and I second the RTM notion.  Who would have guessed the texture map parameter for `surf` was called `'texturemap'`.  ;)

Comment: Haha yes they didn't look too far for that one :)

Comment: Thanks Benoit_11, but my question was about rotated surface, for the normal case there are indeed several functions that perform the texture mapping. Anyway, I found that `campos`, `camtarget` and `camva` give me the information on the camera position\orintation\zoom. now I'll have to find how to translate this info to modify the surface before texture mapping.

Comment: Ok then I guess I misunderstood a bit your question sorry about that!